# Odd estimations by Naive Bayes Classificator

Tags: r, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am currently trying to train a Naive Bayes classificator in order to help me categorize datasets. Each dataset is a log that consists of different possible events. In total I have ~150 events that I code as attributes of log, so it shows how often they occured.

In total, I have ~600 datasets available - of those I use 400 for a training subset and the remaining 200 for a test subset.

When creating the model and applying it to the test subset, something strange occurs: Most of the test data sets get classified as those classes that occur with **least** frequency in the training dataset. 
And most classes that are represented quite well in the training data don't show up at all as classification results. Not really what you would expect, and also not what is correct.

In case code is needed, I will post it later - but I am thinking this has to do something with the way the Naive Bayes works and how my data is structured.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think my issue relates to something called _Skewed data bias_. I will try to apply another classification method.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily debug Naive Bayes(It is not Black Box classifier , unlike Neural Nets, and it is big advantage of NB).

After you trained it look at Empirical log probability of features given a class, P(x_i|y). It's shape `(n_classes, n_features)`. 
After that look at at wrongly classified example features, and you can see why its wrong class.

Comment: How do I do that? If i create a ```bayes_obj``` with ```naiveBayes()```, I know I can access its table with ```bayes_obj$table```. Is that what you mean?